# Promise.all always returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to solve this promise puzzle and I've had 2 questions:

A) I'm wondering why it's returning empty array.  What am i doing wrong?

B) How can I implement async reduce?

B) How can I make it return a Async Array instead of empty array?

**Note:**

> Please make use of `.get` method to iterate through the elements and
>   the return value must be a asyncArray (not a regular array)

Code looks like this:

```js
  /**
     * Async array.
     */
    function AsyncArray(arr) {
      this._arr = arr;
      this.length = arr.length;
    }
    
    /**
     * Asynchronously get the array item of the
     * given index.
     * @param {number} index - array index of the desired item
     * @param {function} callback - called with the array item
     */
    AsyncArray.prototype.get = function get(index, callback) {
      setTimeout(callback, 0, this._arr[index]);
    };
    
    
    /**
     * Async version of Array.prototype.map.
     * @param {AsyncArray} arr
     * @param {function} fn - (item: any) => any
     * @returns {Promise<AsyncArray>}
     */
    function asyncMap(arr, fn) {
      
      let counter = 0; // counter
      const res = []; /// array of promises.
      const len = arr.length;
      
      // Get the length.
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Pending.
        
        while(true) {
          if(counter===len) {
            console.log("before break", res);
            break;
          }
          
          arr.get(counter, item => {
            res[counter] = function() {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                return resolve(fn(item));
              });
            }();
            
            console.log('r',res);
          });
          counter += 1;
        }
      
    
        Promise.all(res).then((r1, rej) => {
          console.log("hello world", r1);
          return resolve(res); 
        });
      });
    }
    
    /**
     * Async version of Array.prototype.reduce.
     * @param {AsyncArray} arr
     * @param {function} fn - (val: any, item: any) => any
     * @returns {Promise<any>}
     */
    function asyncReduce(arr, fn, initVal) {}
    
    
    const arr = new AsyncArray([1, 2, 3]);
    
    // arr.get(1, item => console.log(item)); // Existing
    
    // Expected result: [2, 4, 6];
    asyncMap(arr, x => x * 2).then(arr_ => console.log('asyncMap:', arr_));
    
    // Expected result: 106
    // asyncReduce(arr, (v, x) => v + x, 100).then(val => console.log('asyncReduce:', val));
```

Comment: Avoid mixting direct callbacks with .then() style callbacks. If you are forced to work with an API that employs direct callbacks, then it should be [promisified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) at the lowest level.

Comment: Great suggestion. Can you add more details?

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, but you might consider promisifying `AsyncArray.prototype.get()` either by rewriting it or by writing an `AsyncArray.prototype.getAsync()`. Either way, make sure you have a method that returns Promise. The rest of the code will then simplify significantly.

Comment: Your `asyncMap()` should boil down to one or two lines.

Answer (score 4):

You're putting the result of the `get` calls into the results array *asynchronously* - `res` is empty when you call `Promise.all` on it:

```
      arr.get(counter, item => {
        res[counter] = function() {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return resolve(fn(item));
          });
        }();
      });
      // at this point, nothing has been pushed to res

Promise.all(res)
```

called synchronously after that point won't wait for anything, because none of the items in the array are Promises.

You could push a Promise to the array *synchronously* instead:

```
      res.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
        arr.get(counter, item => resolve(fn(item)));
      }));
```

```js
/**
     * Async array.
     */
    function AsyncArray(arr) {
      this._arr = arr;
      this.length = arr.length;
    }
    
    /**
     * Asynchronously get the array item of the
     * given index.
     * @param {number} index - array index of the desired item
     * @param {function} callback - called with the array item
     */
    AsyncArray.prototype.get = function get(index, callback) {
      setTimeout(callback, 0, this._arr[index]);
    };
    
    
    /**
     * Async version of Array.prototype.map.
     * @param {AsyncArray} arr
     * @param {function} fn - (item: any) => any
     * @returns {Promise<AsyncArray>}
     */
    function asyncMap(arr, fn) {
      
      let counter = 0; // counter
      const res = []; /// array of promises.
      const len = arr.length;
      
      // Get the length.
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Pending.
        
        while(true) {
          if(counter===len) {
            console.log("before break", res);
            break;
          }
          res.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
            arr.get(counter, item => resolve(fn(item)));
          }));
          counter += 1;
        }
      
    
        Promise.all(res).then((r1, rej) => {
          console.log("hello world", r1);
          return resolve(r1); 
        });
      });
    }
    
    /**
     * Async version of Array.prototype.reduce.
     * @param {AsyncArray} arr
     * @param {function} fn - (val: any, item: any) => any
     * @returns {Promise<any>}
     */
    function asyncReduce(arr, fn, initVal) {}
    
    
    const arr = new AsyncArray([1, 2, 3]);
    
    // arr.get(1, item => console.log(item)); // Existing
    
    // Expected result: [2, 4, 6];
    asyncMap(arr, x => x * 2).then(arr_ => console.log('asyncMap:', arr_));
    
    // Expected result: 106
    // asyncReduce(arr, (v, x) => v + x, 100).then(val => console.log('asyncReduce:', val));
```

I'd prefer to use `.map` on an array of the internal array's length to map each `arr.get` call to a Promise in an array, and call `Promise.all` on that array:

```js
function AsyncArray(arr) {
  this._arr = arr;
  this.length = arr.length;
}
AsyncArray.prototype.get = function get(index, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 0, this._arr[index]);
};
function asyncMap(asyncArr, fn) {
  return Promise.all(
    new Array(asyncArr.length).fill().map(
      (item, i) => new Promise(resolve => asyncArr.get(i, item => resolve(fn(item))))
    )
  ).then((result) => {
      console.log("hello world", result);
      return result;
    });
}
const arr = new AsyncArray([1, 2, 3]);
asyncMap(arr, x => x * 2).then(arr_ => console.log('asyncMap:', arr_));
```

For async reduce, have the accumulator be a Promise that resolves to the array after having been pushed in the last iteration:

```js
function asyncReduce(asyncArr, fn, initVal) {
  return new Array(asyncArr.length).fill().reduce(
    (a, _, i) => a.then(resultsArr => {
      // feel free to use asynchronous operations here
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        asyncArr.get(i, resultItem => {
          resultsArr.push(fn(resultItem));
          resolve(resultsArr);
        });
      });
    }),
    Promise.resolve(initVal)
  );
}

function AsyncArray(arr) {
  this._arr = arr;
  this.length = arr.length;
}
AsyncArray.prototype.get = function get(index, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 0, this._arr[index]);
};
const arr = new AsyncArray([1, 2, 3]);
asyncReduce(arr, x => x * 2, []).then(arr_ => console.log('asyncReduce:', arr_));
```

To also return instances of `asyncArray`, just call `new AsyncArray` before resolving, for example:

```js
function asyncReduce(asyncArr, fn, initVal) {
  return new Array(asyncArr.length).fill().reduce(
    (a, _, i) => a.then(resultsArr => {
      // feel free to use asynchronous operations here
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        asyncArr.get(i, resultItem => {
          resultsArr.push(fn(resultItem));
          resolve(resultsArr);
        });
      });
    }),
    Promise.resolve(initVal)
  )
    .then((resultArr) => new AsyncArray(resultArr));
}

function AsyncArray(arr) {
  this._arr = arr;
  this.length = arr.length;
}
AsyncArray.prototype.get = function get(index, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 0, this._arr[index]);
};
const arr = new AsyncArray([1, 2, 3]);
asyncReduce(arr, x => x * 2, []).then(arr_ => console.log('asyncReduce:', arr_));
```

Comment: Well I can&#39;t use map cuz the requirement was to use get() to loop through array thank you for the response

Comment: Should have mentioned that that was a requirement in the question - you can create an empty array from the length of the `asyncArray` instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks so much! Updated the question. I added a IIFE cuz i felt like that returns a promise.  How do we return an async array instead of a regular array in the final result?

Comment: @TechnoCorner Call `new AsyncArray` on the result before resolving

Comment: @CertainPerformance FYI, it looks like `asyncMap` and `asyncReduce` aren't actually applying the passed in function.